# Route that should be matching numbers not matching a zero?

Tags: routes, regex

I have the following in my routes.php file:

```
return array(
    'articles/(?P<sectionId>\d+)/(?P<offset>\d+)' => 'articles/index'
);
```

And while localhost/articles/4/1, for example, routes properly to the template, localhost/articles/4/0 does not and I instead get a 404.

Is there an issue with zeros being picked up as valid URI segments?

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix could be to define an additional route without the offset parameter:

```
return array(
    'articles/(?P<sectionId>\d+)' => 'articles/index',
    'articles/(?P<sectionId>\d+)/(?P<offset>\d+)' => 'articles/index',
);
```

In your template, you'd need to check if the offset parameter is defined, and if not, set it to 0:

```
{{ offset | default( 0 ) }}
```

or

```
{% set offset = offset is defined ? offset : 0 %}
```

**EDIT:**

Another way to solve this is by making the *offset* segment capturing group optional, as per @carlcs' [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8569/1098) to [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8568/is-it-possible-to-define-optional-route-segments/8569#8569) – in my opinion this is a bit more elegant than having two different routes:

```
return array(
    'articles/(?P<sectionId>\d+)(/(?P<offset>\d+))?' => 'articles/index',
);
```

The trick here is wrapping the last segment in parentheses, appending a question mark at the end.

Comment: Mats, probably a good workaround. Just wanted to add that there's also this ternary syntax possible: `{% set offset = offset is defined ?: 0 %}`.

Comment: @carlcs – Nice one, even more succinct :)