# Is it possible to define optional route segments?

Tags: plugin-development, routes

Is it possible to have optional route segments/variables with getCpRoutes() and getSiteRoutes()?

I'd like the following route to work, even if the URI only contains one segment ("myplugin") rather than two ("myplugin/somevalue"):

```
"myplugin/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+)" => array( "action" => "myPlugin/myAction" )
```

How would the regexp look? Is it even possible, or do I need another route pointing to the same action, but omitting the *myVariable* segment?

This question is kind of a follow up to [Route that should be matching numbers not matching a zero?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8524/route-that-should-be-matching-numbers-not-matching-a-zero/8552#8552)

Comment: Did you try to simply make that capturing group optional `myplugin/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+)?` or `myplugin(/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+))?`?

Comment: I did not, and the latter suggestion (```myplugin(/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+))?```) works! Thanks a lot – feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a capturing group optional, simply append `?` to it. In this case you'd need to add an additional group that includes the backslash and make it optional.

```
"myplugin(/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+))?" => array("action" => "myPlugin/myAction")
```

Comment: Thank you – I also edited my answer to http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8524/route-that-should-be-matching-numbers-not-matching-a-zero/8552#8552 as this would solve that issue nicely as well.