# Plugin Routes: Asterisk Token effect from CP Routes

Tags: plugin-development, routes, php, token

I'd like to use the asterisk token functionality that is available in the CP in my plugin. This way I can have an infinite amount of 'pages' under certain routes. In the CP, it looks like **myroute/***

Is it possible for me to get the same functionality in my plugin routes?

Routes have been working amazing for me via the standard:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
    'myroute' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
  );    
}
```

Though when I try the asterisk trick, it doesn't work:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
    'myroute/*' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
  );    
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and/or the way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have tokens in your plugin routes, but you can easily add a segment variable that recreates the asterisk token's functionality with some regex. According to the the [official docs on routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#available-tokens), the asterisk represents

> (...) any string of characters, except for a forward slash (/)

Here's what the defintion for a route with a "asterisk-like" segment could look like:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
    return array(
        'myroute/(?P<asteriskToken>[-\w]+)' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
    );    
}
```

*Note that the string "asteriskToken" will be the variable name for this route segment's value when it is passed to your controller. It could be named anything.*

The above route will match any URIs such as

/myroute/whatever *(asterisk token will be "whatever")*
/myroute/123 *(asterisk token will be "123")*
/myroute//foobar *(asterisk token will be "foobar")*

Coming to your controller, here's how you could look up the asterisk token variable's value:

```
public function actionMyAction( array $variables = array() )
{
   $asteriskToken = $variables[ 'asteriskToken' ];
}
```

Be aware that any calls to /myroute (i.e. without the second segment) will now 404. If this is unwanted – or if you want to define a default value for your asterisk variable – you can make the asterisk token segment *optional*. This is done by wrapping the segment variable in parentheses and appending a question mark at the end (kudos to [@carlcs](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/125/carlcs) for this trick, originally given as an [answer to my question here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/8569/1098):

```
'myroute(/(?P<asteriskToken>[-\w]+))?' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
```

With the latter regex, your route will now also match the following:

/myroute *(asterisk token will be **undefined**)*

...and in your controller, here's how you could define a default value for the asterisk token variable:

```
$asteriskToken = isset( $variables[ 'asteriskToken' ] ) ? $variables[ 'asteriskToken' ] : 'myDefaultAsteriskValue';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for both answering it and also answering what I probably would've run into afterwards. You're the man!

Comment: Happy to be able to help out, @ZackTaylor :)

Comment: So I did run into one issue, which is when the route has special characters in it (even when running through url_encode() first.) For example, route 'myroute/check-this-out' works fine, but if it's 'myroute/check-this-out%21', it leads to a 404. When using the "asterisk token" in CP, this is not an issue and does not lead to a 404. Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: Hi @ZackTaylor, I notice you've created a new thread for the question in your above comment. Here's the link, as a followup: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8754/dynamic-routing-via-plugin-with-special-characters/8760#8760