# Dynamic routing via plugin with special characters

Tags: plugin-development, routes, php

After learning how to use dynamic routing in MyPluginPlugin.php, I quickly ran into the issue of if the URL has special characters from url_encode:

```
public function registerSiteRoutes()
{
return array(
    'myroute/(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+)' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
);    
}
```

And then I process some variables before rendering the template in myPlugin/myAction:

```
 public function actionLoadTemplate( array $variables = array() )
 {
   /*
   process & build $variables
   */

    $this->renderTemplate('layouts/forums/_entry', $variables);

 }
```

This works great if the route looks like `myroute/check-this-out`, however if the route had a special character in it, say it was "check-this-out!", it understandably leads to a 404. But with using url_encode on the URL so it looks like `myroute/check-this-out%21`, it still leads to a 404.

When testing manually in the CP route section, if I create `myroute/*` with the token, I don't get a 404 with those special characters after using url_encode.

Is there a way to modify `(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+)` so that it works with url-safe special characters just like the CP version does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to update the regex to allow for additional characters.  For example, if you want to allow `!`, then this will work:

```
return array(
    'myroute/(?P<myVariable>[-\w\!]+)' => array('action' => 'myPlugin/myAction')
);
```

Note that `\w` is essentially the same as writing `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: But this does work when manually adding the route in CP using the aterisk, as long as the url/route uses url_encode. Characters like "!" aren't being passed in the route, the url_encode() character is (such as %21) There must be a way to do '(?P<myVariable>[-\w]+)' in order to get the same functionality as the CP asterisk token no?

Comment: You're right, I'm an idiot. Updating answer.

Comment: Nifty trick, super good to know. Works perfectly!