# How do I create an advanced route with multiple slugs?

Tags: routes, php, slug, regex

I'm trying to create a route for an RSS feed which allows for the following routes.

```
domain/feed
domain/category/feed
domain/category/subcategory/feed
```

I have the first two routes working and the category fetching logic looks okay to me.

So far in my routes file I have the following

```
'feed' => 'feed/_index.twig',
'(?P<slug>[^/]+)/feed' => 'feed/_index',

// Additional New route
'(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/feed' => 'feed/_index',
```

That last line was added recently as I thought the child category would include the parent category in its route.

I either get a 404 error without that new route, or when I do add that third route I get the following error

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same    
name at offset 27 (craft/app/etc/web/UrlManager.php:387)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is because you've got two named subpatterns with the same name (`<slug>`).  According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/7166444/684, you can do that as long as you use the `(?J)` option in your pattern.  Not sure if that's going to solve your overall problem, so just adding this as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brad nails the problem in [his comment](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10578/how-do-i-create-an-advanced-route-with-multiple-slugs#comment13751_10578):

> The error is because you've got two named subpatterns with the same name (`<slug>`)

And the solution is simple... **Change the name(s) of your subpattern(s)**.

The term `slug` is just a convention of Craft. It doesn't matter what the names are, they can be anything useful to you:

```
(?P<domain>[^/]+)/(?P<category>[^/]+)/feed
```

Whatever values match those named patterns are automatically **passed into the Twig template as "magic" variables**. So your Twig template can now make use of the `domain` and `category` values.

Comment: It's also possible to make segments optional. See this question [Is it possible to define optional route segments?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/8568/125).